# PowerView in Excel 2010

Tags: sql, excel, powerpivot, powerview

Can anybody tell me any difference in PowerView in Excel 2010 and PowerView in Excel 2013? I have already tried looking for differences but couldn't find the information i need.

Answer (score 8):

Power View doesn't exist for Excel 2010. PowerPivot V1 existed for Excel 2010, but it isn't compatible with Power Pivot in Excel 2013 (there is an upgrade process that works some of the time). Power View exists for SharePoint 2010 and 2013 and Excel 2013. There's a good timeline and explanation of Power View for Excel on [PowerPivotPro.com](http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2013/06/powerpivot-vs-power-view-whats-the-difference/)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no PowerView in Excel 2010.